# Regular expression interview

Tags: java, regex

Regular expression rules are defined as

1. '.' Matches any single character.
2. '*' Matches zero or more of the
   preceding element.

The regular expression match should cover entire input string.
eg.

1. isPaternPresent( "zz", "z" ) → false
2. isPaternPresent( "zz", "zz" ) → true
3. isPaternPresent( "zk", ".*" ) → true ( here pattern is dot star )

I cannot understand how eg.3.

How can isPaternPresent( "zk", '.*' ) → true be true ?

Here is what I thought :

1. z is matched to '.'
2. k is matched * and that is whatever character '.' represented. Here '.' represents 'z'

So how can

> zk

matched to

> .*

be true

Comment: `.*` means 'match any character, zero or more times`.

Comment: Sure but does it have to match both characters. I do not understand how it matches both characters. say . matches z then what should k match as ? There is only * left in the pattern and that has to match the preceding character zero or more times. But the preceding character is matched to k.

Comment: it is match any char, then do it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using regex101.com

According to this

> .* matches any character (except newline) Quantifier: * Between zero
>   and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
>   [greedy]

The * is repeating the rule not repeating the match

Comment: This was an interview questions. So cannot do that :(

Comment: what, you can post to SO, but not look up regex101.com - very strange

Comment: I see your point. I did not know about regex101. i will look up there.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is associative! Therefore the `*` will take any expression before it and apply the `seen zero or more times` rule. In your case, it applies the rule to `.` which means 'any character, zero or more times.' If you had, say, `[01]*`, it will mean 'either a 0, or a 1, zero or more times'.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked a similar question on a C# interview (but using '?' instead of '.' for single character wild cards). It bothered me for days, but I finally think I've found something that works. Feel free to convert to java, stress test and comment if you found any errors.

```
public static bool IsPhraseValid(string regex, string phrase)
{
    if (regex.Length == 0 && phrase.Length == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    while(regex.Replace("**","*") != regex)
    {
        regex = regex.Replace("**", "*");
    }
    while (regex != phrase)
    {
        if (regex[0] == phrase[0] || regex[0] == '?')
        {
            if (regex.Length > 1 && phrase.Length > 1)
            {
                return IsPhraseValid(regex.Substring(1), phrase.Substring(1));
            }
            else
            {
                return regex.Length == phrase.Length;
            }
        }
        else if (regex[0] == '*')
        {
            if (regex.Length > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < phrase.Length; i++)
                {
                    if ((phrase[i] == regex[1] || regex[1] == '?') && IsPhraseValid(phrase.Substring(0,i) + regex.Substring(1), phrase))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```